# How do I check if a sublist in a 2D list is in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

my_new_list = [[1,3,7,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

How can I check that a sublist equals `my_list`?

Comment: `if my_list in my_new_list`

Comment: It's like check if a number is in a list of integers or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if `my_list` is in the `my_new_list` just use `in`:

```
>>> my_list in my_new_list
True
```

If you want to know the index of the matching list you can use `index`:

```
>>> my_new_list.index(my_list)
1
```

---

If you think these are too efficient, too easy or too short you can do it manually as well:

```
>>> any(sublist == my_list for sublist in my_new_list) # equivalent to "in"
True

>>> next(idx for idx, sublist in enumerate(my_new_list) if sublist == my_list)  # like "index".
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to check if the numbers in my_list also appear in my_new_list even if they are not in order?

Comment: yes that's possible but should be out of scope for this question. Maybe ask a new question?

Answer (score 0):

You can index built-in function

```
>>> my_new_list.index(my_list)
1
```

Or you can use in :

```
>>> my_list in my_new_list
True
```

You can also use magic function contains

```
>>> my_new_list.__contains__(my_list)
True
```